# Expected number of partitions with a red ball?

Tags: probability, balls-in-bins

Say that we have $k$ red balls and $n-k$ blacks balls for $n$ balls total. Then, say we partition the balls into equal sized groups of size $m$. What is the expected number of groups with a red ball?

It seems clear that I should use linearity of expectation of some sort. I tried calculating the probability that any one group has at least one red ball, but I can't seem to get my equation to match my code simulation result.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What did you calculate as the probability that a particular group has a red ball?

Comment: I figured it would be like the complement of picking black balls one at a time until we have m of them. So $(n-k)/n * (n-k-1)/n * ... * (n-k-m+1)/n$

Comment: No, since the denominator gets smaller each time a ball is drawn - try  $1 - \frac{n-k}{n} \times \frac{n-k-1}{n-1} \times \cdots \times \frac{n-k-m+1}{n-m+1}$  and compare this with your simulation.  Then remember there are $\frac{n}{m}$ groups

Comment: Oh goodness me. That was my problem. Thank you so much for catching my mistake! (Add an answer and I'll accept it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_i$ be an indicator random variable $=1$ if the $i^{th}$ group has a red ball, and $=0$ otherwise.

Then $P[i^{th}$ group has a red ball] $= \left[1 - \dfrac{\binom{n-k}{m}}{\binom{n}{m}}\right]$
Now the expectation of an indicator r.v.  is just the probability of the event it indicates, so $E[X_i] = \left[1 - \dfrac{\binom{n-k}{m}}{\binom{n}{m}}\right]$

By linearity of expectation we have *expectation of sum = sum of expectations*,
$E[\sum{(X_i)}] = \sum{E(X_i)} = \dfrac{n}{m}\left[1 - \dfrac{\binom{n-k}{m}}{\binom{n}{m}}\right]$

Answer (score 0):

If I  understand this  correctly we  take  one  of the  ${n\choose k}$
arrangements of  these balls in  a line  and partition into  groups of
size $m$ of consecutive balls starting  at the left and then ask about
the  expected number  of  groups  containing at  least  one red  ball.
Alternatively  we  may   start  the  computation  by   asking  of  the
expectation of  the number of groups  containing no red ball.  We thus
use a marked generating function as in

$$\left. \frac{\partial}{\partial u}
(uB^m - B^m + (R+B)^m)^{n/m}\right|_{u=1}$$

and get

$$\left. \frac{n}{m} (uB^m - B^m + (R+B)^m)^{n/m-1} B^m\right|_{u=1}
\\ = \left. \frac{n}{m} ((R+B)^m)^{n/m-1} B^m\right|_{u=1}
\\ = \frac{n}{m} B^m (R+B)^{n-m}.$$

Extracting coefficients we find

$$\frac{n}{m} [R^k] [B^{n-k}] B^m (R+B)^{n-m}
= \frac{n}{m} [R^k] [B^{n-k-m}] (R+B)^{n-m}
= \frac{n}{m} {n-m\choose k}.$$

Now to count  the groups with at  least one red ball  we subtract from
the number of groups which is $n/m$ and the result becomes

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{n}{m}
\left(1 -  {n\choose k}^{-1} {n-m\choose k}\right).}$$

This matches the answer that was first to appear.

We may also check this by enumeration as shown below.

```
with(combinat);

ENUM :=
proc(n, k, m)
option remember;
local src, d, grp, run, reds, gf;

    if n mod m <> 0 then return FAIL fi;

    gf := 0;

    src := [seq(R, idx=1..k), seq(B, idx=k+1..n)];

    for d in permute(src) do
        reds := 0;
        for grp from 0 to n/m-1 do
            run := d[1+grp*m..m+grp*m];

            if numboccur(run, R) > 0 then
                reds := reds + 1;
            fi;
        od;

        gf := gf + u^reds;
    od;

    gf;
end;

EXENUM := (n, k, m) ->
subs(u=1, diff(ENUM(n, k, m), u))/binomial(n,k);

EX := (n, k, m) -> n/m*(1 - binomial(n-m,k)/binomial(n,k));
```